# Mathematician whose teacher recommended he stay back a year.

Tags: math-history, mathematicians

Was it true that Fejer's childhood teacher recommended he be held back? I recall such a legend but cannot find any reference to it. I am guessing it is apocryphal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of this story in [Fejer's biography](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Fejer.html) or in [Lipót Fejér by those who knew him](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Fejer_descriptions.html). However, the following sentence from his bibliography gives some credit to this episode of his life.

> Lipót's schooling was in Pécs but at first things did not go well and
>   his father took him out of school for a while and acted as his
>   teacher.

I have no access to the [Dictionary of Scientific Biography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_Scientific_Biography#Electronic_version) but it might be a place to look at.